# How to add a Attibute to TreeNode of asp.net Treeview control

Tags: asp.net

I have a treeview in which on particular node i want's to add rel="nofollow attribute"
But in the TreeNode object i didn't find Attributes.Add method

Please let me know how can i add rel="nofollow" on my particular TreeNode

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your tree node text inside of an anchor (`<a>`) element and apply the `rel='nofollow'` value to the anchor, like this:

C#:

```
protected void TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound(object sender, TreeNodeEventArgs e)
{
    e.Node.Text = "<a rel='nofollow'>" + e.Node.Text + "</a>";
}
```

VB.NET:

```
Protected Sub TreeView1_TreeNodeDataBound(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeEventArgs)
    e.Node.Text = "<a rel='nofollow'>" & e.Node.Text & "</a>"
End Sub
```

Comment: It didn't work
.It resulted in
<a class="tvCategories_0" href="http://mysite/other.aspx" id="tvCategoriest9"><a rel='nofollow'>Other (12)</a></a>

While i want's it  like 
<a class="tvCategories_0" href="http://mysite/other.aspx" id="tvCategoriest9" rel='nofollow'>Other (12)</a>